# Modal Box logic issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, semantic-ui

I have recently used Semantic UI to display a modal box in my app. In the modal box is a for, when the form is submitted the values of the forms feilds go on to be used in various ways. My issue is when the page posts back the form feilds are losing their values?  For instance a text box that was filled out just appears as empty? However if I move the logic outside the Modal Box it all works fine? Also I have a link that when clicked fires an event in a code behind page, however when in the modal box the event does not fire?

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing these strange issue? It would seem from some things I have tried that its the javascript showing the Modal Box which is causing issues. If I manually add a class to show the modal box and disable the javascript which was causing it to show previously my logic then works fine?

Any help one this would be great im running out of things to try.

For Reference:

- Heres the modal box im using http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/definition
- Here is how to show it according to the docs `$('.ui.modal').modal('show');` this is what i believe to be causing the issues

EDIT:

It looks like something in the javascript is rendering the modal just below above the closing body tag regardless of where it is in the context of the website?! This certainly part of the issue, however I fell there is still something else going on

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or something that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I dont think that would help, the modal box is doing what it should by showing the content I give it, it is just breaking the logic that goes along with what it is showing